# Minimal prime ideals of quotient modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring, $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. If $\dim_R M=\dim_R R/\mathfrak{q}$ for all $\mathfrak{q}\in \operatorname{Min}_R M$ and $x\in R$ is $M$-regular, then $\dim_R M/xM=\dim_R R/\mathfrak{q}$ for all $\mathfrak{q}\in \operatorname{Min}_R M/xM$? (Here $\operatorname{Min}_R M$ means minimal prime ideals in $\operatorname{Supp}_R M$.)

I know that $\dim_R M/xM=\dim_R M-1$. Now, let $\mathfrak{q}\in \operatorname{Min}_R M/xM$, then $\mathfrak{q}\in \operatorname{Supp}_R M$. Clearly, $\mathfrak{q}\notin \operatorname{Min}_R M$. Then there exists $\mathfrak{p}\in \operatorname{Min}_R M$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\subsetneq \mathfrak{q}$. Note that $\dim R/\mathfrak{p}> \dim R/\mathfrak{q}$. The result can be obtained if one shows that $\dim R/\mathfrak{p}= \dim R/\mathfrak{q}+1$. I do not know how to do it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Here $Min_R(M)$ means that the minimal prime ideals in the $Suup_R(M)$.

Comment: After modding out $\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ your question reduces to the following: let $R$ be an equidimensional local ring (that is, a ring with the property $\dim R=\dim R/\mathfrak q$ for all minimal primes $\mathfrak q$), and $x\in R$ a non-zerodivisor. Does it follows that $R/(x)$ is equidimensional?

Comment: At present I think the answer to the question is negative, but I'm still missing a counterexample.

Comment: Consider $R$ as in [Nagata's example](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JE) of a noetherian local domain which is not catenary and has dimension $3$. It contains a maximal chain of prime ideals $(0)\subset\mathfrak p\subset\mathfrak m$. For $x\in\mathfrak p$, $x\ne0$ we have that $R/(x)$ is not equidimensional since $\dim R/(x)=2$, and $\dim R/\mathfrak p=1$.

Comment: thanks for the example